# Who got a pardon from Gabriel Narutowicz?

Tags: poland, president

In December 1922 Gabriel Narutowicz was president of Poland and were killed 16th of December. Just after 5 days of being president of country he got assassinated by Eligiusz Niewiadomski.

I found that his only official decision as president was pardon to some Ukrainian from Eastern Galicia. Is it possible to get some more information about it? Why this guy was sentenced to death? What was his name?

Comment: @Mary, accoring to this (unfortunatelly in polish) https://histmag.org/Zamach-na-prezydenta-Narutowicza-18862?fbclid=IwAR3BMLEaukMIx4CzZN4XVD1oQP9VVJXtuJgJo6U3xyfQgaBxBzFEDsBCknA
this Ukrainian was sentenced to death penalty. I am looking for some more info about this guy

Comment: Chasing down [a footnote(92)](https://historia.org.pl/2009/09/12/gabriel-narutowicz-niechciana-prezydentura/) I guess https://www.google.com/books/edition/Gabriel_Narutowicz/YmWcAAAACAAJ has on page 61 som einfo on this. Anyone access to it?

Comment: Polis WP on the assassination is equally vague and ref's Czeslaw Brzoza, Andrzej Leon Sowa Historia Polski 1918–1945, Kraków, 2006 p269, also not even indexed on GG…

Answer (score 3):

Barring getting more information about the person himself, I can certainly see a good reason why **a** Ukrainian from [Eastern Galicia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galicia_(Eastern_Europe)#History) might have found themselves in that situation in late 1922.

> In 1918, Western Galicia became a part of the restored Republic of
> Poland, which absorbed the Lemko-Rusyn Republic. The local Ukrainian
> population briefly declared the independence of Eastern Galicia as the
> "West Ukrainian People's Republic". During the Polish-Soviet War the Soviets tried to establish the puppet-state of the Galician SSR in East Galicia, the government of which after a couple of months was liquidated.
>
> The fate of Galicia was settled by the Peace of Riga on 18 March 1921,
> attributing Galicia to the Second Polish Republic. Although never
> accepted as legitimate by some Ukrainians, it was decided by the
> Conference of Ambassadors on 14 March 1923 and internationally
> recognized on 15 May 1923.

What this glosses over is that the independent state the Ukrainians tried to set up got caught in the middle of of the Ukrainian-Soviet war, then the Russian Civil war, then the Polish-Soviet war, all in this one 5-year period. Both (or all three?) sides captured the area at various points. The Poles got to keep them in their peace settlement with the Soviets.

Comment: I realize this post occupies some nether region between a comment and an answer. Given the lack of info to go from in the question, I thought it might be best to treat this question like we would an identification question, where detailed "clues" are generally considered reasonable posts for answers. If you feel differently, feel free to act as you would to such an answer.

Comment: thanks for the answer. It makes a lot of sense and is valuable (+1). However I don't accept it as I was more interested in name of this guy and confirmed reason of death penalty. That's strange that we don't know such information when it happend 100 years ago, it's not prehistory

Comment: I have looked everywhere and have never seen mention of a pardon. Here are several resources ... the first one in particular mentions he did the following:

1)  Met Cardinal Aleksander Kakowski
2) Offered Ministry of Diplomacy to his recent contender Count Zamoyski
3)  Listened to Piłsudski’s words acknowledging him as leader
4)  Visited Zachęta Art Gallery where he was assassinated. 

https://polishhistory.pl/three-presidents-of-the-second-polish-republic/, https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Gabriel_Narutowicz

Comment: @david, accoring to this: https://histmag.org/Zamach-na-prezydenta-Narutowicza-18862?fbclid=IwAR3BMLEaukMIx4CzZN4XVD1oQP9VVJXtuJgJo6U3xyfQgaBxBzFEDsBCknA
there was a pardon also it was in movie `Death of president`: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2XnZdgnzbdM&t=161s&ab_channel=WFDiF-StudioFilmoweKadr in 1:50. Also found it here: https://www.otwarta.org/gabriel-narutowicz-pierwszy-prezydent-rp-1865-1922/ and here: https://historia.wprost.pl/10281151/prezydent-zamordowany-w-trzecim-dniu-urzedowania-dzis-rocznica-smierci-gabriela-narutowicza.html . However I found it only in polish sources

Comment: @Michu93 ... thanks for the references. I literally spent hours looking for this name, became a bit of an obsession for me, but alas, I did not succeed. Good luck finding this nugget of history.